# How to solve Key Error in views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, web

When I'm trying to fill out the form on the website, it throws me a Key Error. The status of POST http request is 500 and data don't save in db. Here is views.py file:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def bookings(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.load(request)
        exist = Reservation.objects.filter(reservation_date=data['reservation_date']).filter(
            reservation_slot=data['reservation_slot']).exists()
        if exist==False:
            booking = Reservation(
                name=data['first_name'],
                phone_number=data['phone_number'],
                email=data['email'],
                reservation_date=data['reservation_date'],
                reservation_slot=data['reservation_slot'],
            )
            booking.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("{'error':1}", content_type='application/json')
    
    date = request.GET.get('date',datetime.today().date())

    bookings = Reservation.objects.all().filter(reservation_date=date)
    booking_json = serializers.serialize('json', bookings)

    return HttpResponse(booking_json, content_type='application/json')
```

This is models.py:

```py
class Reservation(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    reservation_date = models.DateField()
    reservation_slot = models.SmallIntegerField(default=10)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.surname
```

This is forms.py:

```py
class ReservationForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Reservation
        fields = "__all__"
```

Error message:

```
File "/home/prabhu/Documents/Projects/alcudia-web/my_alcudia/baseweb/views.py", line 50, in bookings
    email=data['email'],
KeyError: 'email'
```

And this is HTML form:

```html
   <p>
   <label for="email">Email: </label>
   <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" maxlength="200" required="" id="email">
   </p>
```

Will be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: Share the HTML form. This is one of the (many) reasons to use a Django form.

Comment: Best would be to share the request data (from the browser debugger) when sending the form as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one element: the [**`name="…"`** <sup>[mdn-doc]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) of the email input element:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" maxlength="200" required="" id="email">
```

that being said, validation of input is tricky, therefore it is better to let a Django form validate the data. You don't have to render that form in the template if you don't want to.

---

> **Note**: Please *don't* use [**`@csrf_exempt`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt) as standard practice: it makes your site vulnerable to [*Cross-site request forgery (CSRF)* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) where one can for example make links that perform POST actions. By working with a CSRF cookie, the *SameSite* policy of cookies will prevent this from happening.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: @PrabhuEgorus: so exactly *what* is not working...

Comment: Still throws KeyError 'email'